# Jenkins blocking/throttling build flows using build-flow-plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have a build flow that runs multiple build flows

**Main Flow**

```
parallel (
    { build("flow1") },
    { build("flow2") },
    { build("flow3") },
    { build("flow4") }
)
```

Each sub flow runs a set of jobs

**Sub-flow**

```
build(job1)
build(job2)
```

Each of the jobs are configured to run on a Jenkins slave with a certain label but I am unable to figure out how to get each job to run on a slave that doesn't have a flow already on it.

ie. both flow 1 and flow 2 queue on the same slave when I have 2 slaves available with the defined label.

Anyone able to help me with configuring blocking/throttling for build flows.

I think the problem lies with the fact they don't take up an executor on the slave.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically jobs build on the last node they built on.  So, I'm assuming both the flyweight jobs last ran on the same slave?

Here are some ways to make one of the flyweights move to another slave.

1. Take one of the slaves offline and kick off flow1.  Then switch places and take the other offline and start up the remaining. Kick off flow 2.  This should put the last place where each flyweight built on different slaves.
2. Add a different label to each slave and target each one separately.  For example, Flow1 targets Node1 and Flow2 targets Node2.  Each flyweight should only go to that label being targeted.
3. Install the [Job Restrictions Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin) and create some kind of complex logic to determine whether the flyweight should build on the node.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think either 2 or 3 is the most applicable to my scenario as taking slaves offline is not a great option for our stability!